# Echo value of a header back to the client

Tags: php

I am trying to extract value form an incoming request's header and then echo it back to the client, but this code doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php 

$custom_header = $_SERVER['X-Forwarded-Host'];

echo "$custom_header";

?>
```

I am passing `X-Forwarded-Host: google.com` as a header in the request and ideally I should get the response `google.com` but the error that I get is `Undefined index: X-Forwarded-Host in C:\xampp\htdocs\reflect.php`

I'm running this script on my local machine using XAMPP.

Comment: Next time simply do `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see actual values

Answer (score 2):

php convert custom headers as HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST

```php
    $custom_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
```